# What is the difference '<Toolbar />' and '{ Toolbar() }' in react render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found useContext(ThemeContext)'s value is not update when use '{ Toolbar() }'  in render.

What is the difference '' and '{ Toolbar() }' in react render or diff?

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const themes = {
  light: {
    name: "light",
    foreground: "black",
    background: "white"
  },
  dark: {
    name: "dark",
    foreground: "white",
    background: "black"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(null);

const Toolbar = props => {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext) || {};
  console.log(`Toolbar theme`, theme);
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: theme.background,
        color: theme.foreground
      }}
    >
      <div>{theme.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState(themes.light);

  const toggleTheme = theme => {
    setCurrentTheme(theme);
  };

  console.log(`currentTheme`, currentTheme);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={currentTheme}>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => toggleTheme(themes.light)}>light</button>
          <button onClick={() => toggleTheme(themes.dark)}>dark</button>
        </div>
        {/* Toolbar() */}
        {/* {Toolbar()} */}
        <Toolbar />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call it as a function (`ToolBar()`), it essentially returns its content, and is not considered a React component as such. If you use `<Toolbar />`, it is a component, and the right way to use it.

In short, calling it as a function is like saying "Print here whatever this function returns", where as using it as `<Toolbar /` is like saying "Render this component here".

The function call will cause the states, context, or effects to fail, so your `useContext` call would not have the intended effect if you do not use the component as a component.

Even if a component is a *functional* component, it should not be used directly as a function.

React contains a lot of magic to have `useContext` and friends to work, but it cannot do so when the component is not used as a component. If you're interested in learning more about the mechanisms behind React, and why `useContext` would not work, [check this article](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/).

Answer (score 0):

In ReactJS you call component like this:

```
<Component />
```

and you call function like this:

```
{nameOfFunction()}
```

if you have any constant for example you print its value:

```
const[value, setValue] = useState("Some Text...");
```

...

```
{value} // would pring Some Text...
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Toolbar />` generates (through `JSX`) [[1]](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAKiEAbARgQwE4wLwwA4Yh4Q4B8MA3gFAwwYCmUArhmDABQ20wA8AJgEsAbl1qlR3ABL0kSEBJ4B6QUPG0AlAG4qAX21V6ADzwgMsPvQBmaJkliWmYYFAHgYAQTx526ylwbMrBwKatxhFAjI6Bg-OhJhPJGomDCKobRKoVq6QA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.8.7&externalPlugins=babel-plugin-syntax-jsx%406.18.0) [[2]](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html):

```
React.createElement(Toolbar, null)
```

While `Toolbar()` is a function call.

[Don't call function components. Render them.](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component)

> This is why you need to use JSX (or React.createElement) when rendering components rather than simply calling the function. **That way, any hooks that are used can be registered with the instance of the component that React creates.**

In your example, `useContext` won't register to the component's instance on calling `Toolbar()` as referenced from the blog post.